# SQL LEFT JOIN SUM One To Many

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the SUM from two different but related tables that have a one to many relationship, but when I add a where condition to the second table the first does not properly sum up the total.  Can this be done in a single query?  I should also note that it is critical that both consider the same set of LocationId's as they come from an outside filter.  I also need the Activityname condition to happen after the join if at all possible.  If that isn't possible then that is fine.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpVisits') is not null
begin
    drop TABLE #tmpVisits
end

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpVisitsByActivity') is not null
begin
    drop TABLE #tmpVisitsByActivity
end


CREATE TABLE #tmpVisits
(
    AccountId int,
    LocationId int,
    Dt DATE,
    TotalVisits int
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpVisitsByActivity
(
    AccountId int,
    LocationId int, 
    EventDate DATE,
    TotalCompleted INT,
    ActivityName varchar(20)
)

insert INTO #tmpVisits
SELECT 1,10,'2018-09-12',12
union ALL
SELECT 1,11,'2018-09-12',20
union ALL
SELECT 1,22,'2018-09-12',10

insert INTO #tmpVisitsByActivity
SELECT 1,10,'2018-09-12',55,'ActivityA'
union ALL
SELECT 1,10,'2018-09-12',1,'ActivityA'
union ALL
SELECT 1,10,'2018-09-12',2,'ActivityB'
union ALL
SELECT 1,22,'2018-09-12',3,'ActivityC'

SELECT SUM(v.TotalVisits) --expecting 42 actual 10
, SUM(a.TotalCompleted) --expecting 3 actual 3
FROM #tmpVisits v
left JOIN #tmpVisitsByActivity a
ON v.AccountId = a.AccountId
AND v.dt = a.EventDate
AND v.LocationId = a.locationid
WHERE v.dt='2018-09-12' AND v.AccountId=1 
AND a.ActivityName='ActivityC'
```

Answer (score 0):

The last criteria makes it so that some in #tmpVisits are excluded when there's no match.

But that's easy to get around.

Move the criteria for a.ActivityName to the `ON` clause, and remove it from the `WHERE` clause.

```
...
LEFT JOIN #tmpVisitsByActivity a 
  ON a.AccountId = v.AccountId AND
     a.EventDate = v.dt AND
     a.LocationId = v.locationId AND
     a.ActivityName = 'ActivityA'
WHERE v.dt = '2018-09-12' 
  AND v.AccountId = 1
```

But it would be better to put the second table in a sub-query.  Otherwise the first SUM could be wrong.

Example snippet:

```
DECLARE @Visits TABLE
(
    AccountId INT,
    LocationId INT,
    Dt DATE,
    TotalVisits INT
);

DECLARE @VisitsByActivity TABLE
(
    AccountId INT,
    LocationId INT, 
    EventDate DATE,
    TotalCompleted INT,
    ActivityName VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @Visits (AccountId, LocationId, Dt, TotalVisits) VALUES
(1,10,'2018-09-12',12),
(1,11,'2018-09-12',20),
(1,22,'2018-09-12',10);

INSERT INTO @VisitsByActivity (AccountId, LocationId, EventDate, TotalCompleted, ActivityName) VALUES 
(1,10,'2018-09-12',55,'ActivityA'),
(1,10,'2018-09-12',1,'ActivityA'),
(1,10,'2018-09-12',2,'ActivityB'),
(1,22,'2018-09-12',1,'ActivityC'),
(1,22,'2018-09-12',2,'ActivityC');

SELECT 
 SUM(v.TotalVisits) AS TotalVisits,
 SUM(ac.TotalCompleted) AS TotalCompleted
FROM @Visits v
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT AccountId, EventDate, locationid, 
    SUM(TotalCompleted) AS TotalCompleted
   FROM @VisitsByActivity
   WHERE ActivityName = 'ActivityC'
   GROUP BY AccountId, EventDate, locationid
) AS ac
ON (ac.AccountId = v.AccountId AND ac.EventDate = v.dt AND ac.LocationId = v.locationid)
WHERE v.dt = '2018-09-12' 
  AND v.AccountId=1
```

Comment: Can this be done outside of the join?  I have a restriction in the BI tool we are using in how the query gets formatted.

Comment: @jreed350z A conditional SUM I'm guessing.  I.e. a `CASE WHEN` in the SUM  for TotalCompleted.  Then you can remove the criteria from the ON and the WHERE.

Comment: Unfortunately the tool will only put the conditions after the where clause.

Comment: @jreed350z but if it does need to be in a WHERE clause. Why not just LEFT JOIN to a sub-query for #tmpVisitsByActivity, and put the criteria for ActivityName in there?

Comment: Because activity name gets appended to the query by the tool only after the where clause.

Comment: @jreed350z If that tool has that limitation, and it really needs to add that criteria? Then I don't see else to solve this. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. Only thing I can propose is to stage the data for the missing records. Thanks!

Comment: @jreed350z Btw, to avoid a wrong result that second table should be grouped. Try out the snippet to see why.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `where` condition clauses in the `join` condition like below, if you want to use a single query.

```
SELECT SUM(v.TotalVisits) --expecting 42 actual 10
, SUM(a.TotalCompleted) --expecting 3 actual 3
FROM #tmpVisits v
left JOIN #tmpVisitsByActivity a
ON v.AccountId = a.AccountId
AND v.dt = a.EventDate
AND v.LocationId = a.locationid
AND v.dt='2018-09-12' AND v.AccountId=1 
AND a.ActivityName='ActivityC'
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this outside of the joins?  I have this restriction in a BI tool we are using.